# Find users which have only read permissions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with three columns: The user, the filename and the permission (enumeration for `"read","write","delete"`).

I don't get any further with the question:

How to find all the user_ids which have ONLY the right to read a file, no other permissions...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM tblUsers
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN permission <> 'read' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The above query selects all `user_id` values having no relation to permissions other than `'read'`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by `not in` with your condition:

```
SELECT * FROM user where permission ='read' and id not in 
(SELECT id FROM user where permission !='read');
```